# Improve location of export tool for career CV

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

The "export to PDF" button in one's career profile is listed under "Settings". Since it has nothing to do with settings it is counter-intuitive to have it placed there.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of [Link to PDF in Careers profile editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262212/159034), which was unfortunately declined a few months ago.

Comment: @KevinBrown Reminds me of the [Beware the Leopard](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40705-but-the-plans-were-on-display-on-display-i-eventually) quote.

Comment: Honestly I really don't think it needs to be declined, I'd keep this open and hope someone from the team looks at this.  The create to pdf being in settings makes absolutely 0 sense in terms of user experience.  This (nor does printing or export to another format) has and never will have anything to due with settings.

Comment: I wasn't even aware there was the ability to export the CV..

Comment: Declining, no longer relevant after the release of Developer Story, and the reorg of the UI there for exporting to PDF